# Visual Studio 2017 Web Deploy fails with ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, web-deployment, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to web deploy a new solution with ASP.NET Core 2 using Visual Studio 2017 but fails when I trying to validate the Connection.

The issue said ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED. 
[image: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED]

However with the same account over the same WEB Server in another solution in Visual Studio 2015 pass the validation.

[image]

P.D. I upgrade to using Visual Studio Professional 2017 Preview.version 15.5.0 Preview 4.0

Comment: No I didn't. The issue is not related to ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED as the message said.

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio 2017 you need to create a second Publish Profile.